# Wordpress: Get all values of a custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm using Verve Meta Boxes. I want to make a menu out of one of the custom fields. How can I return all of the custom field values? For example, if I had a custom select field called "fruit" and as options I have "apples", "oranges", and "bananas", how could I get a complete list of those values, as an array perhaps? I can get the ones associated with a post:

```
get_post_custom_values('fruit')
```

…but I can't work out how to get the whole list.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: After looking around, I think that get_categories() might be the answer. Have not tried it yet, but I'll report back.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case someone still wondering:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE "FIELD_NAME"', OBJECT );
```

Just make sure your postmeta table is "wp_postmeta" (default) and change FIELD_NAME with the name you created for the field in the admin.

Comment: This looks better than my hacky solution. I'll give it a try when I have a chance, but it looks good and I'd bet it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the regular wordpress way by using the get_post_meta function in your loop.

Comment: Doesn't that get only the values associated with a specific post, much like my get_post_custom_values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out:

```
$fruits = trim(get_post_meta($post->ID,'fruits',true)); 
$fruits_array = explode(',',$fruits);
foreach($fruits_array as $f){
   echo $f.'<br/>';
}
```

Basically you need to separate your fruits name with comma in your custom field so that you will be able to explode them into array and echo the values one by one.

Thanks,Dave

Comment: Never saw this, sorry. Again, this would only get the values associated with a single post. I needed to get all available options, whether they applied to a single post or not.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find an elegant solution. What I ended up doing was loop through all of the posts and kept a record of unique values as I can across them, creating an array. Then I used that array to make my navigation.